# Print text along with output of function

Tags: php, function, date

I have a small program designed to out put the date

```
<?php
echo '<p>Ordered on  ';
echo date('F jS g:iA');
echo '</p>';
?>
```

This outputs "Ordered on December 6th 5:25PM", how do i get the function to output "Ordered on December 6th at 5:25PM" instead?

Comment: Have a look at [strftime](http://php.net/strftime) also. It's friendlier as you don't have to escape characters, but rather mark those that are date pieces.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
echo '<p>Ordered on  ';
echo date('F jS \a\t g:iA');
echo '</p>';
```

Comment: ah! I like your method better!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
echo '<p>Ordered on  ';
echo date('F jS'), ' at ', date('g:iA');
echo '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks! I figured the solution was a simple one just wasnt sure how